# Solving a non-linear set of equations with non-exact constant values

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I have a set of nonlinear equations which are related to a physical system. The constants of these equations (light hand side values-LHS) are determined through some measurement methods. It means that the determined constants will not be 100% accurate and so when I solve the equation set through Matlab, I cannot get any answer! For example in one experiment, ideally I should have the following eqs: (X, Y and Z are my constants and a & b are my unknowns)

syms a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3

X1=2/3;

X2=5/3;

X3=2/3;

Y1=5/2;

Y2=1/2;

Y3=1/2;

Z1=2;

Z2=1;

Z3=0;

S = vpasolve([X1==b1-b2*b3/a1,X2==a2-b3^2/a1,X3==a3-b2^2/a1,Y1==a1-b3^2/a2,Y2==b2-b1*b3/a2,Y3==a3-b1^2/a2,Z1==a1-b2^2/a3,Z2==a2-b1^2/a3,Z3==b3-b1*b2/a3], [a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3])

Solving with Matlab, it returns: a1=3, a2=2, a3=1, b1=1, b2=1, b3=1. But, when I get the constant LHS's through my measurement system, each one is a bit less than or greater than the corresponding exact value (e.g. in the above eqs set just consider Y2=0.499 instead of 0.5) and so Matlab cannot solve the equation set any more and returns no answer. Please be advised that I do not know the exact values of my constants and I can only determine them through my measurement system and they vary in each experiment. So, I should change the solving method (or may be its sensitivity) for the above eqs. set in order to be able to give me an answer in case of having non-exact LHS values. Please let me know what would be better to do in this case. Thanks

Comment: Could you type the equation of the model ? Thanks

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for your reply. However, I am wondering I didn't get what do you exactly mean by equation of model. Actually X, Y and Z are coefficients of three ellipses related to: math.stackexchange.com/questions/897720/finding-equation-of-an-ellipsoid/898976#898976

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici continue of above comment: Actually X, Y and Z are coefficients of three ellipses related to the below question (please follow the link) and I extract X, Y & Z through installing 3 perpendicular cameras on my coordinate system. Camera#1 gives me X1, X2 and X3 and camera#2 all Y's and camera#3 all Z's. That's why I told that my coefficients are not exact and 100% accurate. Because I extract them by image processing. However, these very small deviations in values of X, Y and Z cause my set of equationes I described above, not to be solved.(please follow the rest in next comment)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici while when I used the exact values of constants (for a sample hypothetical problem) Matlab can solve the set of eqs. Do you have any suggestion to solve the problem?